# EXCEL finding data from 2nd file

Tags: excel

My problem:

I have 2 excel files and I want to show data from 2nd in the 1st one. I would like to use a formula that uses a cell value from the 1st one and than searches through the 2nd file for a true match. And then writes the value from the 2nd file and puts it into the cell where the formula is residing.

[image: 1]

Picture explanation:

In the (FILE 1) (F5) FORMULA cell (marked green) -> the value from cell (FILE 2) (O5) (marked green) should be input.

Cells marked yellow are the data I'd like to compare from.

Comment: What if the text in file 1 is not the same as the file 2? Lets say that in file 1 its: rw32 and in file 2 its: rw32.1. What then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VLOOKUP has the power to do either selection:

Exact Match:

```
=VLOOKUP(A5,[C:\Files\file2.xlsx]Sheet1!$L$5:$O$9,4,FALSE)
```

Close match, with sorted list:

```
=VLOOKUP(A5,[C:\Files\file2.xlsx]Sheet1!$L$5:$O$9,4,TRUE)
```

Close match with unsorted list:

```
=VLOOKUP(A5&"*",[C:\Files\file2.xlsx]Sheet1!$L$5:$O$9,4,FALSE)
```

Comment: NA means that the text you are searching for has not been found

Comment: I figured so much. But why's the problem 'cos I can see the text in the 2nd file and I know it's there. Just want the formula to help me out 'cos there's alot of data to be transfered from one to another.

Comment: Got it to work. I copied all the relevant data from File2 to a new sheet in File1. And used VLOOKUP. Don't know why it didn't work directly to File 2.